# differential equation question, physics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

"A particle of mass m is attracted towards a fixed point 0 with a force inversely proportional to its instantaneous distance from 0. If the particle is released from rest, at a distance L from 0, find the time for it to reach 0"

My attempt at this question:
Noting the fact $x(0)=L$ and $x'(0)=0$, I tried to set the equation to this problem, $m\frac {d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac {-k}{x}$. Since we are covering laplace transform and gamma functions in my class right now, my attempt was to apply laplace transform to the equation above, however I am having trouble finding the answer. Please help me out. Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Just integrate twice, and use the initial conditions

Comment: Ok, the above comment works, however you stress you are solving these types of ODEs within a framework of Laplace transforms. In order we get a better grasp on where potential issues lie in your attempted solution; please provide your attempt at taking the transform of the second order equation.

Comment: The Laplace transform is not an easy method because the ODE is not linear with respect to $x(t)$ and derivatives.

Comment: ok thank you guys. I'll just abandon the laplace method and do as you guys said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2m\frac {d^2x}{dt^2}\frac {dx}{dt}=\frac {-2k}{x}\frac {dx}{dt}$$
$$m(x')^2=-2k\ln(x)+constant$$
With conditions $x(0)=L$ and $x'(0)=0$ :
$$m(x')^2=-2k\ln(x)+2k\ln(L)$$
$x$ is decreassing, hense $x'\leq 0$
$$x'=-\sqrt{-\frac{2k}{m}\ln{\frac{x}{L}}}$$
$$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\ln(L)-\ln(x)}}=-\sqrt{\frac{2k}{m}}dt$$
$$\int_{x=L}^{x=0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\ln(L)-\ln(x)}}=-\sqrt{\frac{2k}{m}}T$$
where $x(T)=0$

The change of variable $\sqrt{\ln(L)-\ln(x)}=y$ transforms the integral into the well-known Gauss integral.
$$L\sqrt{\pi}=\sqrt{\frac{2k}{m}}T$$
$$T=L\sqrt{\frac{\pi m}{2k}}$$

Answer (score 0):

The relation of mass and $k$ is not given, set their fraction to $k/m=1/2$. Solve $\ddot x=-1/(2x)$. Multiply with $\dot x$, integrate once
$$
\frac12(\dot x(t)^2-\dot x(0)^2)= -\frac12\,\ln|x(t)|+\frac12\ln|x(0)|
\implies \dot x(t)=\pm\sqrt{-\ln(|x(t)|/L)}
$$
This is not an easy integral.